# How do I limit the ListView slug to a number of choices in Django?

Tags: django, listview

Here is the code

`models.py`

```
class Submission(models.Model):

    CAR = 'car'
    TRUCK = 'truck'
    VAN = 'van'
    SUV = 'suv'
    CAR_TYPES = (
        (CAR, 'Car'),
        (TRUCK, 'Truck'),
        (VAN, 'Van'),
        (SUV, 'SUV'),
    )

    submission_type = models.CharField(_('Submission Type'), max_length=20, choices=MEDIA_TYPES, default=CAR)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'),  max_length=100, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_submission')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    date_submitted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

`views.py`

```
class SubmissionCategoryList(ListView):
    model = Submission
    template_name = 'submission/submit_cat.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(SubmissionCategoryList, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(submission_type=self.kwargs['slug']).order_by('-date_submitted')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SubmissionCategoryList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

`urls.py`

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', SubmissionCategoryList.as_view(), name='submit_category'),
```

The code works fine.  When I go to `localhost:8000/car/` It shows the list view for only the `CARS` submission_type, etc.  But, when I type in a url that isn't a part of the choices in `CAR_TYPES`, for example, `localhost:8000/boat/`, django still shows the template for this view.  My question is: How do I limit the number of choices the slug should accept? And, if it is not a part of the `CAR_TYPES` choices, how do I get it to ignore this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to [Anzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3849456/anzel) I figured out a great solution to this problem.  I'm putting this here for anyone who needs this.

I created a `reference.py` file that looks like this.  You can call it whatever you like, I just call it reference because it's what it does.

```
from enum import Enum


class CarTypes(Enum):
    CAR = 'car'
    TRUCK = 'truck'
    VAN = 'van'
    SUV = 'suv'
```

I changed my `models.py` to import `reference.py`
I changed `choices` in `submission_type` to `choices=tuple([(auto.name, auto.value) for auto in CarTypes])`

```
from .reference import CarTypes


class Submission(models.Model):

    submission_type = models.CharField(_('Submission Type'), max_length=20, choices=tuple([(auto.name, auto.value) for auto in CarTypes]), default=CarTypes.CAR)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'),  max_length=100, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_submissions')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    date_submitted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And here is the final working `views.py` for categories

```
from .reference import CarTypes


class SubmissionCategoryList(ListView):
    model = Submission
    template_name = 'submission/submit_cat.html'
    CAR_TYPES = [auto.value for auto in CarTypes]

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.kwargs['slug'] in self.CAR_TYPES:
            queryset = super(SubmissionCategoryList, self).get_queryset()
            return queryset.filter(submission_type=self.kwargs['slug']).order_by('-date_submitted')
        else:
            return Http404

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SubmissionCategoryList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['submission_type'] = self.kwargs['slug']
        return context
```

You can put this same `queryset` in a `DetailView` and it should work when a user searches `site.com/car/2` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried validating your "slug" in views?

```
views.py
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.kwargs['slug'] is not None and self.kways['slug'].lower() in project.settings.CAR_TYPE:
        # return your queryset.filter ...
    else:
        # return other template or redirect to other views.

project.settings.py
CAR_TYPE = ['car', 'truck', 'van', 'suv']
```

or, simply just edit url regex:

```
(?P<slug>car|truck|van|suv)
```

not the best approach but definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you!  Adding that to the `get_queryset` method did the trick.